# convert StringArray to DateArray

Tags: android, datetime

I have entered dates in the form of string "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" to my sqlite database. I have taken it all as a String array and have send it to a graph activity. In the graph activity I have tried to convert it to a date object, in the format " dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss " , but I am able to convert it only to this particular format  Wed Jan 15 03:54:30 GMT+05:30 2014, due to which I am not able to display my graph. How can i convert it to date format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"

**Services activity**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
              {

                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) 
                       {
                          new Thread(new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                 Intent tIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GraphActivity.class);
                                 tIntent.putExtra("tempArray", TArray);
                                 tIntent.putExtra("dateArray", TSArray);
                                 startActivity(tIntent);
                            }
                            }).start();
                       }
```

**Graph activity**

```
Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        double[] TArray=extras.getDoubleArray("tempArray");
        String[] TSArray=extras.getStringArray("dateArray");

         int dateArraySize=TArray.length;
         Date dateArray[]=new Date[TArray.length];
         String[] targetArr = TSArray;

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        for (int i=0;i<TArray.length;i++)
        {

        try {
            //converting String date to Date

            Date result=df.parse(TSArray[i]);
             dateArray[i]= result;
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("dateArray",String.valueOf(dateArray[i]));
        }
```

**Logcat**

```
05-15 16:38:56.991: D/TSArray(13743): 15-05-2014 04:37:04
05-15 16:38:56.991: D/TSArray(13743): 15-05-2014 04:38:56
05-15 16:38:58.151: D/TSArray(13743): 15-05-2014 04:37:04
05-15 16:38:58.151: D/TSArray(13743): 15-05-2014 04:38:56
05-15 16:38:58.151: D/TSArray(13743): 15-05-2014 04:38:58
05-15 16:38:58.861: D/TSArray(13743): 15-05-2014 04:37:04

05-15 16:39:04.481: D/dateArray(13743): Thu May 15 04:37:04 GMT+05:30 2014
05-15 16:39:04.481: D/dateArray(13743): Thu May 15 04:38:56 GMT+05:30 2014
05-15 16:39:04.481: D/dateArray(13743): Thu May 15 04:38:58 GMT+05:30 2014
05-15 16:39:04.481: D/dateArray(13743): Thu May 15 04:38:58 GMT+05:30 2014
05-15 16:39:04.481: D/dateArray(13743): Thu May 15 04:38:59 GMT+05:30 2014
05-15 16:39:04.481: D/dateArray(13743): Thu May 15 04:39:00 GMT+05:30 2014
```

Comment: you mean you cannot create Date objects from the strings in the database ?

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi : Yes. You can see it from my logcat. The first set of values are the values in my database and the second the values after conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat.format(Date)`, this will make a `String` in a needed format:

```
df.format(dateArray[i])
```

Comment: format() converts Date to String right? Im trying to convert String to Date.

Comment: you already doing proper conversion via `parse`. But by calling `String.valueOf(dateArray[i])` you just get default output format

Comment: @Ansu in such a case, what's the problem?

Comment: My format of Date is different from the String date that I am  converting. That is the problem.

Comment: @Ansu it's still unclear for me what's the problem. By specifying the pattern of `SimpleDateFormat` you can both parse String of the following format to Date object or format the string representation of Date object. You get valid Date object, but by calling just `String.valueOf(dateArray[i])` you get default string representation, not the one you've specified at the pattern earlier